# Check with masterpage if the user existing on table of MySQL in c#

Tags: c#, mysql, master-pages

In the masterpage of website in C#, I have adding :

```
public static string ObjectPropertyName
{
    get
    {
        return HttpContext.Current.Session["ObjectPropertyName"].ToString();
    }
    set
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session["ObjectPropertyName"] = value;
    }
}
```

And with this sql query check if the user existing in table of MySQL :

```
sql = @String.Format(" SELECT * FROM dotbl ");
sql += String.Format(" WHERE ");
sql += String.Format(" UPPER(PropertyName) IN (?) AND Aut IS NOT NULL; ");

...
...
Container.ObjectPropertyName = username.ToString().ToUpper();
```

Everything works fine if the user is already in the table, but I get this error if the user is not present in the table :

> return
>   HttpContext.Current.Session["ObjectPropertyName"].ToString();

Error :

> Object Reference Not Set to an Instance of an Object

How to do resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Add an "if" statement.

```
    public static string ObjectPropertyName
    {
        get
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Session["ObjectPropertyName"] != null)
            {
                return HttpContext.Current.Session["ObjectPropertyName"].ToString();
            }
            return null;
        }
        set
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session["ObjectPropertyName"] = value;
        }
    }
```